# Error MSB3073 The command "ng build --aot" exited with code 9009

Tags: visual-studio-2017, angular7, asp.net-core-2.1

I created Angular7 application using VS2017 by following this [documentation](https://www.talkingdotnet.com/how-to-create-an-angular-6-app-with-visual-studio-2017/). Whenever I build the application in VS2017 it failed, but I used **ng build** command in command prompt then the application build succeeded without any issues.

**Error:**

Error   MSB3073 The command "ng build --aot" exited with code 9009.

[image]

So, can any one help me on this issue.

Comment: I have the same issue